# Android: Path not displayed after DIFFERENCE OP

Tags: android, path

Hello I'm new to with Android dev and I'm facing a pbm during my first tries.

I have a "ball" following a path.
This part of code is ok (the ball is following the path).
But after I've changed the path it is no more displayed.

Path seems to be ok because the "ball" is following the correct Path.
But I can't see it...

Here is an abstract of the code

```
void init() {
    paint = new Paint();

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(1f);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);      
    paint.setTextSize(40);

    pathBall = new Path();
    pathBall.moveTo(0, 0);
    pathBall.lineTo(300, 0);
    pathBall.lineTo(300, 300);
    pathBall.lineTo(0, 300);
    pathBall.close();

    measure = new PathMeasure(pathBall, true);
    length = measure.getLength();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(pathBall, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(matrix[0], matrix[1], 5, paint);
}


void addPath() {
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(50, 0);
    path.lineTo(50, 100);
    path.lineTo(100, 100);
    path.lineTo(100, 0);
    path.close();

    Region region1 = new Region();
    region1.setPath(pathBall, clip);

    Region region2 = new Region();
    region2.setPath(path, clip);

    region1.op(region2, Op.DIFFERENCE);

    pathBall = region1.getBoundaryPath();

    measure.setPath(pathBall, true);
    length = measure.getLength();
}
```

In a loop I'm doing the following to recalcule the ball position :

```
while (keepDrawing) {
    pos += 5;
    if (pos > length) {
        pos = (int)(pos - length);
        addPath();     // To change path when 1 turn is done by the ball
    }

    measure.getPosTan(pos, matrix, null);

    postInvalidate();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(20);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I did not understand why my path is correct but not displayed any more.
Does any one have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution.
I don't understand why but now it works.
I've simply added a close() to my pathBall :

```
pathBall = region1.getBoundaryPath();
pathBall.close();
```